# flat concrete roof with weathering course leaking in many places

Tags: repair, concrete

It is about 30 yr old building with flat concrete roof with weathering course on top. It started leaking in many places during rainy season. The roof area is about 1200 sq.ft open.what is the remedy.

Comment: ... replace the roof treatment?

Answer (score 2):

A new layer of waterproof material; generally referred to (here) as a re-roof , though of course you would not be replacing the concrete roof. Depending exactly what you mean by a "weathering course" that will probably be getting replaced, removed and replaced on top of a new waterproof membrane located under it, or covered by the new roof system.

Re-roofing is generally the best/most economical time to consider whether you might benefit from adding insulation to your roof to mitigate heat and/or cold passing through it.